# How often can an account be written to per block?

Tags: anchor

I have a game with a high score and every move in the game is writing into the high score account. At how many transactions per block will this lead to a problem?
An option would be to remove the high score account and only write to it when the game is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current actual limit on sequential writes to one account is 12M compute units per block. This is based on a max of 48M compute units per block, and 4 banking threads that process the transaction.

In general, it's best to avoid write-locking one account in the design of your program. For example, spl-token does *not* write-lock the mint for a token during transfers, because then it's impossible to parallelize token transfers for a given int.

You can see where the per-account constant and others are defined at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/2448486106f738c3bd66940babfbf1eb09a56d59/cost-model/src/block_cost_limits.rs#L69

Answer (score 2):

I've have not been able to find an official source on this, but here are my findings:

Solana has a variable block-size depending on the demand at any given point in time. From a few sources, I've found that the maximum theoretical block size is 128MB, with a max serialized transaction size of 1232 bytes. Assuming you're filling the block with max-size transactions, that'd clock in at 103,896tx/block. Another source from Reddit cites maximum block size closer to 77mb, which would leave us with 62,337tx/block.

The likely best course of action would be writing to the account once after the game is over to ensure this bound isn't hit.

EDIT: The numbers I've given are assuming extremely high levels of demand that the network could theoretically hit. In current practice, one could certainly get away with doing writes after every move

*Sources used:*

- https://www.systango.com/blog/all-you-must-know-about-solana-blockchain-platform
- https://www.yahoo.com/now/solana-vs-polygon-developer-perspective-151000538.html
- https://www.reddit.com/r/solana/comments/q1dksc/comment/hfht1yq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Comment: Thank you. I think there is also the component the account being blocked for some time and having only 400ms per block.