# Is There a Limit To How Many People Can Transfer SOL Into a "Pot" Account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions, program, transfer

I'm building a game and want to give players the ability to pool SOL into a PDA account that is distributed to the player that wins. I've read about write-locked accounts, but usually only in the context of custom SPL-tokens, not SOL. I'm wondering if this could become a bottleneck and cause transaction failures if there is too much traffic and if so, what the best solution might be. Since it's SOL, there aren't any new accounts being created on transfer or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

The pot account that you choose to receive SOL will need to be write-locked in order to receive funds, just like an SPL token account.

The main bottleneck exists at the network level involves the amount of compute units including this account, which is capped at 12 million compute units per block. Practically speaking, you probably don't need to worry about this for your program.

You can read more about that at https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/7247/84

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yea, that's a huge amount of wiggle room for what I'm doing. I don't know that I'd get THAT much traffic per block. Sounds like I'll be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Wrapped Sol for your application.

You can know more about Wrapped Sol [here](https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/wrapped-sol)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey can you give more information on why wrapped SOL would provide anything extra? Otherwise this answer is not actually answering the question